# Material Stepper | Header Navigation causing method to execute twice

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper, mat-stepper

I'm using a stepper with dynamic forms in each step. I have created methods for back and next button which I call on click of next and back button like this:

```
 <button (click)="previousStage()" mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious>BACK</button>
 <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext (click)="nextStage()">Next</button>
```

Now I also want to move backward and forward when user clicks on header navigation so I have created a method for that as well:

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true (selectionChange)="onNavChange($event)">
```

Inside the onNavChange(event) .. I call the method next or sub depending on the step name.

The problem is that when I click on next button then it is called twice... first it calls the onNavChange($event) and then the method called on next button.

How can I ensure that it is called only once? Is there a way that onNavChange() gets executed only when clicked on header?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full or example `nextStage($event)` method I analyze the issue. However, I use in my templates `(click.prevent)`. In your example try

```
<button mat-raised-button matStepperNext (click.prevent)="nextStage()">Next</button>
```

Also, what checks are doing for the `currentStep`? That way when you're on the `currentstep` you only navigate.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution will be to get a hold of the stepper using ViewChild:

`@ViewChild('stepper', {static: false}) stepper: MatStepper;`

Now you can use the observable itself, and use RXJS operators in order to filter the dobule request:

```
stepper.selectionChange.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but it was an easy solution. This is what I did:
1. Removed function calls from Next and Previous buttons. I kept **matStepperPrevious** for back and **matStepperNext** for next button.
2. Called the desired method only on **selectionChange()**.

I noticed that selectionChange() is invoked when there is a change in the step and this can happen on click of either the header or buttons so I called my function only on selectionChange().